# After beta testing your app in TestFlight, do you have to re-upload for public release?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, app-store-connect

After beta testing your app in TestFlight, do you have to re-upload the app build for the Apple Review Team for Public Release or can you release the build for release right away to the App Store?

Answer (score 1):

No you dont need to re-upload binary go into test flight section & switch off testflight testing. After this you can release that version.